# linq to entities inheritance query problem

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to perform a linq to entities query on a table that's inherited using [Table per Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc765425.aspx).

The problem I'm having is that I can't get at the properties on the Inhertied table only the properties on the Base Table.

```
var qry = from i in _DB.BaseTable
where i is catalogueModel.InheritedTable
// Field Doesn't Exist
// && i.InheritedTableField == "Value"
select i;
```

When I try to cast the Inherited Table to it's type...

```
var qry = from i in _DB.BaseTable
where i is catalogueModel.InheritedTable
&& (i as catalogueModel.InheritedTable).InheritedTableField  == "Value"
select i;
```

...the code compiles but i get a cool error which reads

> Only text pointers are allowed in work
>   tables, never text, ntext, or image
>   columns. The query processor produced
>   a query plan that required a text,
>   ntext, or image column in a work
>   table.

I suppose my question is How are you supposed to access the properties of the Inherited tables in linq to entities when using [Table per Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc765425.aspx)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use .[OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301729.aspx)():

```
var qry = from i in _DB.BaseTable.OfType<InheritedTable>()
          select i.InheritedTableField;
```

Comment: Graig, A Tip of the hat to you sir. It appears you've solved my problem. Much'o Thanks'o.

BTW - Know of any good references for Linq to entities queries when using inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use IS

```
var qry = from i in _DB.BaseTable where i is InheritedTable select i.InheritedTableField;
```

Here are a few others to help (using Entity SQL)

```
var q = SELECT VALUE c FROM OFTYPE(yourcontext.yourbaseclass, yourmodel.yoursubclass) AS c

var q = SELECT VALUE c FROM yourcontext.yourbaseclass AS c where c IS NOT OF (yourmodel.yoursubclass)
```